# How to change javascript custom-select into react?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

everyone. Right now I'm working on a project using React. I am having a difficulty to do custom select in React as I am new to this language. Does anyone know how to do custom-select in React and I want to be displayed exactly as the dropdown picture that I put in this question. Thanks in advance.

I copy the JavaScript code for custom-select under ComponentDidMount(). However, my select box is not appear on my website.

```
  //JavaScript code of custom-select
  var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
    a = document.createElement("DIV");
    a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
    a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    x[i].appendChild(a);
    b = document.createElement("DIV");
      b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
    for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
      c = document.createElement("DIV");
        c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
        c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var y, i, k, s, h;
        s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
        h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          if (s.options[i].innerHTML === this.innerHTML) {
            s.selectedIndex = i;
            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
              y[k].removeAttribute("class");
            }
            this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
            break;
          }
        }
        h.click();
      })
      b.appendChild(c);
    }
    x[i].appendChild(b);
    a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      closeAllSelect(this);
      this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
      this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
    })
  }

  function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
    var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
    y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt === y[i]) {
        arrNo.push(i)
      } else {
        y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
      }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
        x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
      }
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
  $('.select-items div:first-child').addClass('same-as-selected');

  //dropdown.js
  <div class="col-md-6 comparision-dropdown">
     <div class="parent-dropdown">
        <div class="custom-select" style={{Width:'106px'}}>
           <select>
              <option value="1" selected>One</option>
              <option value="1" >One</option>
              <option value="2" >Two</option>
           </select>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-select" style={{Width:'180px'}}>
          <select>
            <option value="January" selected>January</option>
            <option value="January" >January</option>
            <option value="February" >February</option>
          </select>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

[image: This is how the dropdown should be displayed on my website]

This is how the dropdown should be displayed on my website

Comment: If you want to dynamically import those files in react you could use react lazy, here's the docs: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html

Comment: rather than reinventing the wheel I think you should google something like react-select, this might be faster for your development process

Comment: You need to learn first JSX and react before you start writing react code, like with everything. If you actually learn how to use React this would be easy task for you. Just read or watch any React intro tutorial.